# apache: absolute ErrorDocument relative /var/www/?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, errordocument

My apache `VirtualHost` contains an `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test/
  ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

The file `/var/www/html/test/error/404.txt` does exist.

When trying to access a non-existing file, I get an error-in-a-error message from apache:

> The requested URL /foo was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

The error log contains:

> [error] File does not exist: /var/www/html/test/foo
>   [error] File does not exist: /var/www/error/404.txt

Why does apache make the error document path relative to `/var/www` (apache user's home dir) instead of relative to the virtual host's `DocumentRoot`, as [described in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#errordocument)?

> URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), ...

---

This happens with Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error was the default configuration:

```
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
```

Removing this line made it work.